# How to set maxLength in Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have been trying to set `maxLength` for `editText` in Anko but I am unable to find the right function.

```
 editText()
        {
            id = R.id.et2
            hint = "age"
            inputType = android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            maxLines = 1
        }.lparams {
            below(R.id.et1)
            alignParentLeft()
            leftOf(R.id.bt1)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `maxLength` property

```
 editText()
            {
                id = R.id.et2
                hint = "age"
                inputType = android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
                maxLines= 1
                maxLength = 10
            }.lparams {
                below(R.id.et1)
                alignParentLeft()
                leftOf(R.id.bt1)
            }
```

Refer documentation : [Anko Attributes](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/idea-plugin/attrs.json)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the maxLength attribute isn't available for numeric input types. However, this can be solved quite easily by adding an input filter.

Like this:

```
val inputFilters = arrayOfNulls<InputFilter>(1)
inputFilters[0] = InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)
editText.filters = inputFilters
```